# Update JSON string field in yaml using yq

Tags: shell, jq, yq

Have a file **sample.yaml**

```
---
action: "want-to-update"
foo: |-
    {
        "a" : "actual A",
        "b" : "actual B",
        "c" : "actual C"
    }
---
action: "dont-want-to-update"
foo: |-
.
.
.
```

Need to update value in `a` field from `actual a` to `updated a`

Tried to update with `yq` and `jq`

```
yq 'select(.action == "want-to-update").foo' sample.yaml | jq '.a = "updated a" | tostring' | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} yq 'select(.action == "want-to-update").foo = {}' -i sample.yaml
```

Getting output as below:

```
---
action: "want-to-update"
foo: |-
  {"a":"updated a","b":"actual B","c":"actual C"}
---
.
.
```

But I want the prettier version of above:

```
---
action: "want-to-update"
foo: |-
    {
        "a" : "updated A",
        "b" : "actual B",
        "c" : "actual C"
    }
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fromjson` and `tojson`, you can decode and encode JSON on the fly, so all of this can be done with just one call to [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (no [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) and no command substitution needed):

```bash
yq -i 'select(.action == "want-to-update").foo |= (
  fromjson | .a = "updated a" | tojson
)' sample.yaml
```

Comment: Note: To have this one-go solution with a compact formatting of the JSON data, replace `tojson` with `@json` (and for aesthetical symmetry, also `fromjson` with `@jsond`).

Comment: Note #2: `tojson` also accepts an indentation size as parameter, so maybe `tojson(4)` would better fit your original formatting of the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, remove `tostring`

```bash
json=$(
    yq 'select(.action == "want-to-update").foo' sample.yaml \
    | jq '.a = "updated a"'
)
escaped_quotes=${json//\"/\\\"}
yq 'select(.action == "want-to-update").foo = "'"${escaped_quotes}"'"' sample.yaml
```

```yaml
---
action: "want-to-update"
foo: |-
  {
    "a": "updated a",
    "b": "actual B",
    "c": "actual C"
  }

---
action: "dont-want-to-update"
foo: |-
  "ok"
```